# How to create and if user is exits just update other data in django rest framework

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I want to create an API in the Django rest framework. Task is Highlight will create and when the same user has the same book id then it'll update . I added the code below. but I'm not finding any way to update the values without creating new data.

models.py

```
class HighLight(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    book = models.ForeignKey(
        BookDetails,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        related_name='book_highlight'
    )
    customer = models.ForeignKey('user_profile.CustomerProfile', on_delete=models.CASCADE,null=True,blank=True)
    
    start = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    end = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)

    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
```

Serializer.py

```
class HighLightSerializer(serializers.Serializer):

    class Meta:
        model = HighLight
        fields = ('id','book','customer','start','end',)
```

Views.py

```
class HighLightedBooks(generics.ListCreateAPIView):

    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated,)
    serializer_class = HighLightSerializer
    authentication_classes = (TokenAuthentication,)
    
    
    
    
    def perform_create(self, serializer):
        book_id = self.request.data.get('book', False)
        try:
            customer = CustomerProfile.objects.get(user=self.request.user)
        except Exception as e:
            raise ValidationError('You must have to update your profile before submitting a review')
        
        serializer.save(customer_id=customer.id, book_id=book_id)
```

Answer (score 0):

`ListCreateAPIView` generic view configures the serializer to create a new entry on `save`.

In order to update a `HighLight` via generics, you should create a new view with `UpdateAPIView` and a new URL (for instance `/path/<int:pk>`).

You can hook into `perform_update` in the fashion you do for `perform_create`.